# can not able to get session id from magento site to android app

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, app

we are trying to devolop a android app for magento site

we followed the follwing link to create a api username and key in magento admin panel.

https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magebridge/administration/596-step-by-step-create-a-magento-api-user

from this api key and username we are getting the session id .

but we did lot of customization for this site.

after customization we can not able to get the session id.

please help what i have to do to get the session id for the customized site.

this error we are getting : http://sitename.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call like this
http://videomergerapp.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1

And you can get session token by trying codes as follow:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://videomergerapp.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('username', 'password');
```

Comment: How to check existing session token,if it is valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution. There was a problem with an extension.

once we disabled that extension. we got the session id.

From now onwards, once we use any exxtension, than we have to check whether it supports our app or not-:)